# How to show git log history in reverse order at the Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

How can I show my git log history in reverse order at my Android Studio, Version Control Window?

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio Terminal :

```
git log --reverse
```

[image]

Or

Click show history icon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Studio provided custom filter by Date,User,Path ,Branch look at below screenshot.

[image]

But it's more flexible way to use this git terminal command :

```
git log --reverse
```